# 2017 Macbook Pro volume is too low

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, sound-volume

My cat walked on my keyboard/mouse/touchbar and now my volume is too low. It happens with both headphones and using the internal speakers. I've looked at Audio/Midi settings and everything seems okay there, but testing still plays the audio too quiet.

What kind of secret "low volume" setting did my cat engage and how do I reverse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved my own problem with an [NVRAM/SMC/PRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063). The world may never come to understand what secret Mac fu cats possess.

Comment: Great. I was trying to post an answer with NVRAM reset. And you got it on your own.https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5154856 - > You can see for the answer on it too why NVRAM reset helped you (beside your cat sexy walk) :)

Comment: This answer still works as of today.   No sound, low volume, .... why Apple never gets this right?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I don't want to restart the computer. A simple `sudo pkill -9 coreaudiod` did the trick for me. You can also try this command if your mac has no sound.

Comment: Quick and easy solution here. Thanks :)

Comment: @EricChen Absolutely :)